# Decoding assembly callback

Tags: c, assembly, callback, gdb, x86-64

In my assembly code, I have a line that says

```
    callq *%rcx
```

I understand that this calls the function callback pointed to by rcx. However, I have no idea what/where this callback is implemented/what it does. How can I figure this out?

Comment: Use a **debugger**

Comment: @user3847447 `%rcx` denotes a CPU register. If there isn't a previous other command which shows what explicit address is loaded - using the debugger is really the only way to find out. (I guess "debugging by head" is not an option in this case...)

Comment: Look up what address `%rcx` points to and disassemble the memory at that address.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I figure this out?

```
(gdb) x/10i $rcx
```

will show you what code will start executing immediately after the `CALL`.

If that code has a label (i.e. is part of a named function), GDB will show that as well, and you can guess (or ask the linker with `-Wl,-y,name`) whence that code came from.

If that code does not have a label, there is no easy way to find out the origin. If you can relink the executable, linker `-Wl,--print-map` can help.